# Syntastic installation issue: ^M file endings

Tags: vim, cygwin, syntastic

I'm trying to install Syntastic for Vim using Cygwin. After completing step 2.1 and the cloning part of step 2.2 in the [installation guide](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) of Syntastic, I find that now when I run vim I get the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/rjw08/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: exists("g:loaded_syntastic_notifier_autoloclist") || !exists("g:loaded_syntastic_plugin")^M
line   39:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing /home/rjw08/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: exists("g:loaded_syntastic_notifier_balloons") || !exists("g:loaded_syntastic_plugin")^M
line   67:
E171: Missing :endif
Error detected while processing /home/rjw08/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim:
line    1:
E15: Invalid expression: exists("g:loaded_syntastic_checker") || !exists("g:loaded_syntastic_plugin")^M
```

There were a few more errors, but they follow this basic format. From what I understand, file endings in the listed files are incorrect (i.e. ^M). However when I open these files in Vim, there does not seem to be any ^M endings to delete.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on the offending files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the file into vim, then `:set fileformat=unix` and `:wq` should fix it.

PS: you don't see the ^Ms because vim thinks it is a dos file (it probably says `[dos]` in the status bar after loading).

Answer (score 1):

This command will transform every file to a unix file in the ~/.vim/bundle directory.

```
find ~/.vim/bundle -type f -follow -print|xargs dos2unix
```